# call script or function in update panel after every refresh click inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net

my header portion is

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SimpleAdmin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("ul").hide("normal");
        $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("#home").show("normal");
        $(".box").children(".h_title").click(function () {$(this).next("ul").slideToggle(); });
    });
</script>   
</head>
```

And my body portion

```
<body>
<form id="form" runat="server">  

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>    

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>        
<asp:DataList ID="dtlheader" runat="server" Width="189px">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" onmouseover="this.style.background='#683372'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#3e3d3b'"  style="background-color: #3e3d3b;">
         <tr>
         <td>
            <div class="box">
              <div class="h_title" style="color: #FFFFFF"><%# Eval("header") %></div>
                <ul>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dtlsubtitle" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" onmouseover="this.style.background='#ececec'"
                                                    onmouseout="this.style.background='#ececec'"  style="background-color: #ececec;"><tr><td>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click"><%# Eval("subtitle") %></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td></tr></table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>  
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

this is a script of **switchmenu** 
On page 1st load it is working good but on doing linkbutton clicking which is inside,
than after script does not get work again.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this: `"javascript", "function();"`?

Comment: Also, if you want to register a script related to an `UpdatePanel`, you need to attach to it, not to the `Page`. ie: `RegisterStartupScript(myUpdatePanel, myUpdatePanel.GetType()`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK i had tried this " ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "javascript", "function();", true);" but not working, how shall i call script name function() on every refresh of update panel

Comment: You can't name a script `function()`. That's what I've pointed out on my first comment.

Comment: If you mean by `function()` is this `$(function () {});`, you're going the wrong way. That's just a jQuery code to execute everything within it on the page load event.

Comment: @MelanciaUK than what shall i do to make it run properly

Comment: @MelanciaUK hey i had written Response.Write("hi"); in the linkbutton click event and alll of it is working fine...how??

Comment: There's a lot of confusion going on here. When you click on the LinkButton, and on the LinkButton click event handler you write something using the Response.Write() method, of course it'd work. I'm thinking your problem (what you're asking) is regarding the Javascript function to be called (client side), the one you're trying to register with the RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35143/discussion-between-mitesh-jain-and-melanciauk)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, this should solve it:

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {        
    $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("ul").hide("normal");
    $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("#home").show("normal");
});

function lbClicked(obj) {
    $(obj).next("ul").slideToggle(); 
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click" onclientclick="lbClicked(this)"><%# Eval("subtitle") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You don't need the line below, which is wrong anyway
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "javascript", "function();", true);

}
  protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You don't need the line below, which is wrong anyway 
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "javascript", "function();", true);
}
```

Comment: protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Write("hi");
}.doing this my script is working very well.....i just want to know that on writing response.write how can a script started working very well in update panel

Comment: I had tried working on your answer but my script is not working at all

Comment: Sorry, but I honestly don't get what are you trying to do then. Maybe someone else can help you.